# f.select and f.text_field on one object in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, models

Is it possible to have a number of options e.g. f.select or the user can type in anything e.g f.text_field on one object?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is called a combo box.  There is no direct support for this in rails or basic html.  You will need to use javascript.

Check this out: [jquery.combobox](http://jquery.sanchezsalvador.com/page/jquerycombobox.aspx)